# VIM remove space between successive curly brackets with a single mapping

Tags: vim

I am working on a jinja file in vim which was poorly formatted for some reasons.
I have many variables in curly brackets with a space left in between the curly brackets. Ex:

```
this is my jinja variable { { foo } }
```

I would like to remove the extra space between the curly brackets. The desired outcome is

```
This my jinja variable {{ foo }}
```

This just works fine if I chain two substitute commands in the command mode.

```
:%s/{ {/{{/g | %s/} }/}}/g
```

However, if I wrap the substitute commands in a mapping `noremap <leader>cb :%s/{ {/{{/g | %s/} }/}}/g <CR>`, only the first substitution is executed, but not the second. Here is the corresponding output

```
This my jinja variable {{ foo } }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could ask this, instead, on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ Delete this one if you do.

Comment: @Rob I leave this one here since I already got an answer - but I ll make sure to post next time on vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: FWIW, SO recently changed their policy regarding closing answers and they expanded the acceptable topics quite a bit so Vim questions now quasi-officially have their place here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using one substitution by taking advantage of capture groups:

```
nnoremap <leader>cb :%s/{ {\(.*\)} }/{{\1}}/<CR>
```

Not that this will fail if you have the pattern twice on a line like:

```
{ { hello } } ... { { world } }
```

because it'll be turned into:

```
{{ hello } } ... { { world}}
```

Someone might come along with an actual explanation on *why* your way doesn't
work, so you should probably not accept this answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works like a charm! Let's see if I get an explanation in why my approach doesn't work. If not, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @greghor glad it helped, although I just realised that this will fail if you have the pattern twice on a line (see updated answer). So the `/g` here was superfluous (I removed it from the command so as not to mislead others).

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping doesn't work because of the `|`:

```
noremap <leader>cb :%s/{ {/{{/g | %s/} }/}}/g <CR>
                                ^
```

You can rewrite it in several ways:

```
noremap <leader>cb :%s/{ {/{{/g \| %s/} }/}}/g <CR>
noremap <leader>cb :%s/{ {/{{/g <bar> %s/} }/}}/g <CR>
etc.
```

See `:help map-bar`.

---

By the way, `:noremap` covers too many modes, which you might find problematic in the long run. If you want a normal mode mapping, be explicit about it:

```
nnoremap <leader>cb :%s/{ {/{{/g <bar> %s/} }/}}/g <CR>
```